# Oracle ApEx LDAP Authentication across multiple domains

Tags: oracle, active-directory, oracle-apex

I am trying to set up LDAP Authentication to allow users to log in to my application using their Microsoft AD credentials. The application is on ApEx 4.2.5.

I was able to successfully enable this when specifying the DN string's domain as mydomain\%LDAP_USER%.

The main issue is that we have users from at least 3 different domains within the same directory.

Is there a way to make this string more dynamic to include multiple domains?

Comment: all ldap requests have to go to the same server? Do you have code to test with dbms_ldap? How would you want to handle the 3 different domains for users who want to log in?

Comment: I haven't tested anything with dbms_ldap as of yet; I've solely been working within ApEx itself using the built-in LDAP Authentication scheme options. When I specify either US\%LDAP_USER% or CA\%LDAP_USER%, the authentication scheme works to log into the application for users within the named domain. All users in these various domains are on the same server. I'm not sure how to handle calling these different domains. Ideally, it would be something that could work in the standard LDAP scheme settings, but I suspect I'll need to create a custom scheme using the APEX_LDAP functions.